# Бедность (-) не порок и подобные

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить тире в предложениях? (с обоснованием)

Бедность не порок.
Жить значит поступать честно.
новый год это елка, мандарины, подарки.
Хороший спортсмен вот пример.
Ее жизнь как легенда.
Говорить не правду великий грех.

Answer (score 2):

*Бедность не порок.* - Если перед сказуемым, выраженным существительным в именительном падеже, стоит отрицание ***не***, то тире не ставится.

*Жить - значит поступать честно.* - Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если подлежащее выражено формой именительного падежа существительного, а сказуемое неопредёленной формой глагола или если оба они выражены неопределённой формой (жить - поступать).

*Новый год - это елка, мандарины, подарки...* - Тире ставится перед *это,* *это есть, это значит, вот,* если сказуемое, выраженное существительным в именительном падеже или неопределённой формой глагола, присоединяется посредством этих слов к подлежащему.

*Хороший спортсмен - вот пример.* - Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженным существительным в именительном падеже (без связки).

*Ее жизнь как легенда.* - Тире не ставится, если сказуемое присоединяется союзом *как* или другими сравнительными союзами (словно, будто).

*Говорить **неправду** - великий грех.* - Тире ставится, если один главный член выражен неопределенной формой глагола, а другой – именем существительным.

---

[Правило-1](http://pismoref.ru/2689515672.html), [правило-2](http://www.rusyaz.ru/pr/ptr.html).

Answer (score 1):

Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба выражены им.падежом, Перед словом это,значит,это значит, вот, присоединяющими сказуемое к подлежащему.

Жить – значит поступать честно, Новый год – это елка, мандарины, подарки; Хороший спортсмен – вот пример;  Говорить неправду – великий грех.

Но тире не ставится пере отрицанием,если в роли связки выступают сравнительные союзы как, будто, словно.
Бедность не порок;Ее жизнь как легенда.